# Oracle sql:How to pass outer block value to inner block

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Below is my query. I want to pass outer block value to inner block. outer block phase_name value should be passed to inner block. But that's not happening

```
    select  phase_name,
    (select  count(*) from projects,PHASES WHERE UPPER(projects.status) LIKE 
    '%'||phase_name||'%') count_pr
    from PHASES
```

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51747499/edit) to show your sample data including the data types, your full query and your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the INSTR function

for example:

```
INSTR('Corporate Floor','or')
```

would return the location where the first occurrence of the string 'or' took place in the sting 'Corporate Floor'.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by using alias name for the table in the outer block.

```
    select  phase_name,
    (select  count(*) from projects,PHASES WHERE UPPER(projects.status) LIKE 
    '%'||ph.phase_name||'%') count_pr
    from PHASES ph
```